# Sed: Searching for a string length and character specific

Tags: regex, string, replace, sed

I've been searching for a few hours now for a way to find a string containing 21 numeric characters and place a return in front of the string itself. Finally i found the solution using:

```
sed -r 's/\b[0-9]{21}\b/\n&/g'
```

Works great!

Now i have a new set of data containing 21 numeric characters but adding to that there is some alphabetic characters at the end of the string with a variable length of 3 to 10 characters.

Sample input:

```
169349870913736210308ABC
168232727246529300209DEFGHI
166587299965005120122JKLMNOPQRS
162411281984306600005TUVWXYZ
```

What i would like is to have a space between the numeric and the alphabetical characters:

```
169349870913736210308 ABC
168232727246529300209 DEFGHI
166587299965005120122 JKLMNOPQRS
162411281984306600005 TUVWXYZ
```

Do note the 16 which every number starts with. I've tried using:

```
sed -r 's/^\b[0-9]{21}\+[A-Z]{3,10}\b/ /g' filename
```

But i couldnt get it to work because i dont know and couldnt find how to specifically search for a string containing an exact amount of numeric characters combined with alphabetical characters of a special length. I've found a lot of helpfull questions on this website, but this one i couldnt find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use capturing group.

```
sed -r 's/^([0-9]{21})([A-Z]{3,10})$/\1 \2/' filename
```

Answer (score 3):

Search from left to right first non numeric character (`[^0-9]`) and replace it by a whitespace and the matching (`&`) non numeric character:

```
sed 's/[^0-9]/ &/' file
```

Output:

```
169349870913736210308 ABC
168232727246529300209 DEFGHI
166587299965005120122 JKLMNOPQRS
162411281984306600005 TUVWXYZ
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a space after the first 21 characters, like so:

```
sed 's/^...................../& /g'
```